# How can I get with PowerShell the project version in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, powershell-2.0, post-build-event

I'm writing a simple `PowerShell` script for creating `NuGet` packages on `Post-build` event. For this I'd like to set the package version automatically to the project version. Currently it's hardcoded in my command:

```
nuget pack .\MyProject.csproj -properties configuration=release -version 1.0.0 -outputdirectory .\NuGet\Packages
```

Is there a way to change the above command to something like this (pseudo code):

```
var currentVersion = Get-ProjectVersion();
nuget pack .\MyProject.csproj -properties configuration=release -version $currentVersion$ -outputdirectory .\NuGet\Packages
```

and then push the package with the same version to the `NuGet` server?

```
nuget push .\MyProject.$currentVersion$.nupkg -configfile .\NuGet.config
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by getting the projectversion from Assembly.cs

```
function Get-ProjectVersion([string] $ProjectName)
{
    $project = Get-Project -Name $ProjectName
    $assemblyPath = $project.ProjectItems.Item("Properties").ProjectItems.Item("AssemblyInfo.cs").Properties.Item("FullPath").Value

    $assemblyInfo = Get-Content -Path $assemblyPath
    if (!$assemblyInfo)
    {
        return $null
    }                

    $versionMatches = [regex]::Match($assemblyInfo, "\[assembly\: AssemblyVersion\(`"((\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.?(\d*)){1}`"\)\]")

    if (!$versionMatches -or !$versionMatches.Groups -or $versionMatches.Groups.Count -le 0)
    {
        return $null
    }

    return $versionMatches.Groups[1].Value
}
```

Call and use it like this

```
$currentVersion = Get-ProjectVersion -ProjectName "MyProject"
nuget pack ".\MyProject.csproj" -properties "configuration=release" -version "$currentVersion" -outputdirectory ".\NuGet\Packages"
nuget push ".\MyProject.$currentVersion.nupkg" -configfile ".\NuGet.config"
```

Warning:

`$project = Get-Project -Name $ProjectName` can only be used inside the *Package Manager Console* in *Visual Studio*. As an alternative you could add the assembly file location as a parameter.